# Mysql - разница между двумя датами

Tags: mysql

Есть такой вопрос, к примеру есть таблица деталей и таблица статусов их обработки. Вывожу разницу в днях между минимальной и максимальной датами окончательно обработанных деталей (finished=1)

Для вашего удобства сделал https://dbfiddle.uk/rfVkqCTe

```
create table detail
(
    detail_id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(34) not null,
    finished smallint(1) unsigned default 0 not null
);

create table status
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    detail_id int not null,
    status varchar(256) not null,
    datetime datetime not null
);


INSERT INTO detail VALUES
(1, 'ножка стула', 1),
(2, 'вакуумный поршень', 1),
(3, 'ухокрут' ,0),
(4, 'сумка болтов' ,0);

SELECT * FROM detail;

INSERT INTO status VALUES
(1, 1, 'получено со склада', '2022-09-22 17:27:46'),
(2, 1, 'обработка на токарном станке', '2022-09-23 17:27:46'),
(3, 1, 'обработка лаком', '2022-09-24 17:27:46'),
(4, 1, 'возвращено на склад', '2022-09-25 17:20:46'),
(5, 2, 'получено со склада', '2022-09-20 17:27:46'),
(6, 2, 'обработка пескоструем', '2022-09-21 17:27:46'),
(7, 2, 'возвращено на склад', '2022-09-30 17:27:46'),
(8, 4, 'получено со склада', '2022-09-10 17:27:46'),
(9, 4, 'поступило в цех', '2022-09-11 17:27:46');


SELECT * FROM status;



#несколько деталей
SELECT detail.detail_id, detail.name,
       DATEDIFF(MAX(datetime),
                MIN(datetime)
               ) AS Duration 
FROM status, detail
WHERE detail.detail_id = status.detail_id AND finished=1 AND detail.name LIKE '%у%'
GROUP BY detail_id
ORDER BY detail.detail_id DESC
LIMIT 10;



#avg
SELECT MIN(x.Duration), AVG(x.Duration), MAX(x.Duration)
FROM
(
    SELECT detail.detail_id, detail.name,
       DATEDIFF(MAX(datetime),
                MIN(datetime)
               ) AS Duration 
    FROM status, detail
    WHERE detail.detail_id = status.detail_id AND finished=1 AND detail.name LIKE '%у%'
    GROUP BY detail_id
    ORDER BY detail.detail_id DESC
    LIMIT 100
) x;
```

| detail_id | name | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | вакуумный поршень | 10 |
| 1 | ножка стула | 3 |

Вроде бы все получилось, но парочка вопросов появилась:

- сортировка и лимит произошли на выводе результата, но как отсортировать и лимитировать детали перед обработкой MYSQL?
- сложно ли вывести средний результат и мин/макс дней? (к примеру средний 6 дней, минимальный 3 дня, максимальный 10 дней).

Comment: *как отсортировать и лимитировать детали перед обработкой MYSQL?* Встречный вопрос - а зачем? для получения результата это не нужно... чтобы сервер попыхтел лишнего? *сложно ли вывести средний результат и мин/макс дней?* `AVG()`. PS. Не используйте comma-style JOINs, они устарели лет на 20...

Comment: @Akina на comma-style не обращай внимание, то была заготовка из инета. Тупанул, редко пишу код, разобрался https://dbfiddle.uk/isRqLrxa забыл про представление запроса таблицей

Comment: в общем все получилось https://dbfiddle.uk/e70621wD